# Is it possible to test chat application on two emulator?

Tags: android

I have create a chat simple chat application using asmack lib, and openfire, but when I'm testing it on emulator I'm always getting presence status unavailable, where as same user is available on my openfire server.

I have tested my code for talk.google.com server it work seamlessly, but when I'm testing with open fire I always get unavailable presence status. I have tried various things, like set the subscription option to both in openfire setting.

I have written the following code for setting presence status:

```
Presence presence  = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);  
presence.setStatus("Online, Programmatically!");
presence.setPriority(24);
presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);
connection.sendPacket(presence);
      try {
           Thread.sleep(10000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
      }
```

But when I run my following code I always get presence status is unavailable:

```
Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
// Ignored events public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {}
public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {}
public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {}
public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
System.out.println("Presence changed: " + presence.getFrom() + " " + presence);
}  
@Override
public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub}
});
    try { Thread.sleep(5000); } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) { }
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();              
for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {                         
    Presence subscribed = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribed); 
    subscribed.setTo(entry.getUser()); 
    connection.sendPacket(subscribed);
    Log.d("JWP", "RosterEntry " + entry);
    Log.d("JWP", "User: " + entry.getUser());
    Log.d("JWP", "Name: " + entry.getName());
    Log.d("JWP", "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
    Log.d("JWP", "Type: " + entry.getType());                 
    Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
    Log.d("JWP", "Presence Status: "+ entryPresence.getMode());
    Log.d("JWP", "Presence Type: " + entryPresence.getType());
    Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
    if (type == Presence.Type.available){
    Log.d("JWP", "Presence AVIALABLE");
    Log.d("JWP", "Presence : " + entryPresence);
    }
}
```

Why would this happen?  I have tried different things, but I haven't found an exact solution.